# Typescript: warning for possible undefined access in strict mode

Tags: typescript

I'm using Typescript with `"strict": true` in the `tsconfig.json`. Unfortunately, I don't get a warning, if I'm doing this:

```
let x: any = { test: false }
let y = x.asdf   // this is undefined, but I don't get a warning
```

This code actually is still ok, but this one crashes:

```
let x: any = { test: false }
let y = x.asdf.jjj   // TypeError: Cannot read property 'jjj' of undefined
```

Is there a possibility to show warnings, if a property may be undefined? I want to be warned, so that I can first check, if the property exists.

By the way, the config works, because

```
let x = notDeclared
```

shows, that `notDeclared` cannot be found.

Do I need a linter for this?

**UPDATE**

Depending on all comments (thanks for it), I have to be more specific. The above code is just an example, but I have this issue in these cases, where I really don't have any idea about what will be in the `x`-object. For example:

```
let x = JSON.parse(...)    // the result is any
```

Then I cannot say, what's in the parsed object. I could access anything and while `x.asdf` is just `undefined`, `x.asdf.jjj` will crash the complete application. Would be nice, if a linter or sth. like this would warn me, if I'm too stupid to see this problem ;)

Comment: Well, don't use any. any means: stop bothering me with type checking and let me do whatever I want as if it was plain old JavaScript. You got what you asked for.

Comment: You've explicitly declared `x` to be `any`, so you've basically opted out of type checking for anything related to `x`. If you remove the `: any`, you should get an error when accessing `asdf` property.

Comment: This is just an example... I was running to the problem, when I parsed a string with `xml2js`. The result is `any`...

Comment: Ok... sorry. Thinking about it a little bit more, made it clear. `any` just can be anything (make sense ;)). If I'm using it or if I'm getting it from somewhere, I have to check everything. Unfortunately, there is (yet) no real optional chaining like in Swift. Thanks for your help!

Comment: TypeScript can't possibly tell you that a property doesn't exist on an object it it knows nothing about the type of the object.

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately, I don't get a warning, if I'm doing this

Because you used the `any` type annotation. `any` essentially switches many compile time checks and is a developers way of telling the TypeScript compiler *I know better... don't check this for me*.

## Fix

Remove the `any` annotation:

```
let x = { test: false }
let y = x.asdf   // ERROR
```

OR use the correct annotation:

```
let x:{ test: boolean } = { test: false }
let y = x.asdf   // ERROR
```

## Answer on the Update

> where I really don't have any idea about what will be in the x-object

Neither does TypeScript. TypeScript can only really protect against *compile time* type errors. You need to be able to define the type up front in order to have TypeScript check it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is, that I don't know anything about the x-object. It was just an example, as you see in my comments above and in my edit of the question.

Comment: Added `Answer on the Update` 